# task scheduler without startboundary

Tags: c++, winapi, task, windows-task-scheduler

I am using [msdn's tasks scheduler sample trigger code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/boot-trigger-example--c---)  for creating a task and triggering an executable at logon. The code works fine, but even tho i create the task using an admin account, the task trigger doesnt run the program as an administrator account.. This is the code they provide, as well the link anchored above. What kind of code segments can i add so that the executable gets triggered with elevation ?

```
/**********************************************************************
 This sample schedules a task to start notepad.exe when a user logs on.
**********************************************************************/

#define _WIN32_DCOM

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <cstdlib>

//  Include the task header file.
#include <taskschd.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "taskschd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")

using namespace std;


int __cdecl wmain()
{
    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeEx failed: %x", hr);
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set general COM security levels.
    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeSecurity failed: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create a name for the task.
    LPCWSTR wszTaskName = L"Logon Trigger Test Task";
 wstring wstrExecutablePath = L"C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\admin.exe";


    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create an instance of the Task Service. 
    ITaskService* pService = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_ITaskService,
        (void**)&pService);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed to create an instance of ITaskService: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Connect to the task service.
    hr = pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(),
        _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ITaskService::Connect failed: %x", hr);
        pService->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the pointer to the root task folder.  This folder will hold the
    //  new task that is registered.
    ITaskFolder* pRootFolder = NULL;
    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(L"\\"), &pRootFolder);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Cannot get Root Folder pointer: %x", hr);
        pService->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  If the same task exists, remove it.
    pRootFolder->DeleteTask(_bstr_t(wszTaskName), 0);

    //  Create the task builder object to create the task.
    ITaskDefinition* pTask = NULL;
    hr = pService->NewTask(0, &pTask);

    pService->Release();  // COM clean up.  Pointer is no longer used.
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed to create a task definition: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the registration info for setting the identification.
    IRegistrationInfo* pRegInfo = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_RegistrationInfo(&pRegInfo);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get identification pointer: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }
    hr = pRegInfo->put_Author(_bstr_t(L"Author Name"));

    //hr = pRegInfo->put_Author(L"Author Name");
    pRegInfo->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot put identification info: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create the settings for the task
    ITaskSettings* pSettings = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Settings(&pSettings);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get settings pointer: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set setting values for the task. 
    hr = pSettings->put_StartWhenAvailable(VARIANT_TRUE);
    pSettings->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot put setting info: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the trigger collection to insert the logon trigger.
    ITriggerCollection* pTriggerCollection = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Triggers(&pTriggerCollection);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get trigger collection: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Add the logon trigger to the task.
    ITrigger* pTrigger = NULL;
    //TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON
    hr = pTriggerCollection->Create(TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON, &pTrigger);
    pTriggerCollection->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot create the trigger: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }
    
    ILogonTrigger* pLogonTrigger = NULL;
    hr = pTrigger->QueryInterface(
        IID_ILogonTrigger, (void**)&pLogonTrigger);
    pTrigger->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) 
    {
        printf("\nQueryInterface call failed for ILogonTrigger: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pLogonTrigger->put_Id(_bstr_t(L"Trigger1"));
    if (FAILED(hr))
        printf("\nCannot put the trigger ID: %x", hr);

    //  Define the user.  The task will execute when the user logs on.
    //  The specified user must be a user on this computer.  



    hr = pLogonTrigger->put_UserId(_bstr_t(L"DESKTOP-OH8C7VT\\name"));
    pLogonTrigger->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot add user ID to logon trigger: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Add an Action to the task. This task will execute notepad.exe.     
    IActionCollection* pActionCollection = NULL;

    //  Get the task action collection pointer.
    hr = pTask->get_Actions(&pActionCollection);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get Task collection pointer: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Create the action, specifying that it is an executable action.
    IAction* pAction = NULL;
    hr = pActionCollection->Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC, &pAction);
    pActionCollection->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot create the action: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    IExecAction* pExecAction = NULL;
    //  QI for the executable task pointer.
    hr = pAction->QueryInterface(
        IID_IExecAction, (void**)&pExecAction);
    pAction->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nQueryInterface call failed for IExecAction: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set the path of the executable to notepad.exe.
    hr = pExecAction->put_Path(_bstr_t(wstrExecutablePath.c_str()));
    pExecAction->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot set path of executable: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Save the task in the root folder.
    IRegisteredTask* pRegisteredTask = NULL;

    hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(
        _bstr_t(wszTaskName),
        pTask,
        TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
        _variant_t(L"S-1-5-32-544"),
        _variant_t(),
        TASK_LOGON_GROUP,
        _variant_t(L""),
        &pRegisteredTask);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nError saving the Task : %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\n Success! Task successfully registered. ");

    // Clean up
    pRootFolder->Release();
    pTask->Release();
    pRegisteredTask->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @rustyx interesting, `Local System` doesn't work but i will try `System` and with `Local Service` it creates the task but i see no messagebox from the program, which is how it is coded

Comment: system seems to be ok. @rustyx the only problem is, the executable doesn't run, so it becomes useless. It is a logontrigger, and i think it is looking for SYSTEM users login ?

Comment: @rustyx according to <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/security-identifiers-in-windows">here </a> it belongs to administrator group, i need to check

Comment: *the executable doesn't run, so it becomes useless* Check if it is "run only when user is logged on" in your task schedule, try to use logontype: `TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN` in [`RegisterTaskDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-itaskfolder-registertaskdefinition).